# Typescript - Get the index of an array based on a property value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say you have a typescript interface, and an array of that interface:

```
// - Typescript Interface
interface Event {
    eventName: string;
    eventShape: unknown;
}

// - Typescript Array
type Events = Event[];
```

I know you can tell typescript to use a specific index of the array like this:

```
// - Example Type Array Type
type MyEventsType = [
    {
        eventName: 'event1',
        eventShape: number,
    },
    {
        eventName: 'event2',
        eventShape: string,
    },
];

// - Example usage
const myFunction = <MyEvents extends MyEventsType> 
(myEvent: MyEvents[1]) => {
    myEvent.eventShape; // Typescript understands this is a string
};
```

But how can you make typescript infer the index based on an eventName value?

```
// - Utility Function
type ExtractEventNames<T extends Events> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { eventName: infer Name } ? Name : never;
};

// - Desired example
const myFunction = <EventName extends ExtractEventNames<MyEventsType>[number]>
(eventName: EventName) => {
    eventName; // Typescript knows this is either 'event1' | 'event2'
    // if eventName is 'event1' I want the "number" to be 0
    // if eventName is 'event2' I want the "number" to be 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a utility function that does what I was hoping for:

```
// - Utility Functions
type ExtractEventNames<T extends Events> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { eventName: infer Name } ? Name 
    : never;
};

type ExtractIndexByEventName<T extends Events, E extends 
ExtractEventNames<T>[number]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { eventName: E } ? K : never;
}[number];

// - Desired example
const myFunction = <
    EventName extends ExtractEventNames<MyEventsType>. 
    [number], 
    EventData extends MyEventsType[ExtractIndexByEventName<Events, 
    EventName
>]['eventShape']>
(eventName: EventName) => {
    // EventData is the shape of the provided eventName
};
```